# How to force the PDF file contained vector plot?

Tags: visualization

When drawing large matrices using `ArrayPlot`, it will be blurred, while small matrices will not

Example:

**the small matrix**
`Export["test.pdf", ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 100}]]]`

> [image]

If we zoom the left bottom corner got [image]

However, using code `Export["test.pdf", ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}]]]`, if we zoom the left bottom corner of **the large matrix** got:

> [image]

Even using argument `"CompressionLevel" -> 0`, it stills blurred

So how to force the PDF file contained vector plot if drawing large matrix?

PS：
Although the size of the illustrations in the book of NKS is huge, they are all vector graphics.
https://wolframscience.com/nks/p67--more-cellular-automata/

Comment: most likely the graphics in the "pdf" generated is not vector graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried various things until I tried `Mesh`. The file size is now at 109k.

```
t1 = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 100}]
  , PlotRange -> All
  , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
  , Mesh -> True
  , ImageSize -> Full
  , MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity
  ]
Export["testsmall.pdf", t1]
```

[image]

The gray mesh lines lines cover the individual squares at bigger dimension values and there is a dot left at the centre of each square at high enough ImageSize; so I kept increasing the the `ImageSize` options for the large case. Also played with various `MeshStyles` to get here. Without the mesh the dithering takes over.

```
t2 = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}]
  , PlotRange -> All
  , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
  (*,Mesh\[Rule]True
  , MeshStyle\[Rule]{Directive[Red,Thickness[0.0005]],Directive[
  Thickness[0.0005]]}*)
  , ImageSize -> 6400
  , MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity
  ]
Export["testlarge.pdf", t2]
```

The filesize is at 11.8 MB.

- So my **best guess** is that `ImageSize` needs to be adequate or otherwise the blurring happens.
- Mesh lines do not scale? with `ImageSize` (or at least adequately) clouding the unit square, but i am not positive about that and couldn't locate more info.
- There may be other curious interactions going on due to the color scheme selected/specified through the `PlotRange` parameters.

The answer is not definitive for which I apologize.

[image]

Comment: I just ran into this same problem.  Definitely frustrating.  It does seem that `ImageSize` is the important parameter.  Simply turning on the `Mesh` without increasing `ImageSize` leads to weird effects like (as far as I can tell) vector mesh overlaying a rasterized set of squares.